# Python 3.5 dictionary comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to compare all elements of one dictionary to make sure they are in a second with the correct number. I am new at Python so I know there is something simple I am probably missing and I have been working on this one problem for hours so my code is likely very ugly and wrong. Here is an example of what I have so far.

```
try:       
    for key in dict_one:
        if dict_two.get(key, 0) == dict_one[key]:
           del dict_one[key]
           if dict_one[key] < 0 :                
              return False
        else:
             return True
except KeyError:
   pass
```

I have tried `all(dict_two.get(key,0))` as well and it didn't work.  The final output should check that you can spell a word from `dict_two` using the words in `dict_one` `True` if you can, `False` if you can't so if `dict_two` word requires three Es then `dict_one` should have 3 Es or return false. Or two Ns if you were spelling bunny ex `dict_one = {b: 1, u: 1, n:1, y:1, x: 3}` and `dict_two ={b: 1, u: 1. n: 2, y:1}` `False` because you need 2 Ns in the word and `dict_one` only has one.

I can get `dict_two` to populate correctly when I enter a word and `dict_one` properly pulls random numbers and amounts of those numbers. And I can get them to compare properly for letters included in each, I just can't get it to produce right answer of `True` or `False` for the number of letters needed. I feel I am close to an answer, but then just make it worse when I try new things and dig my hole deeper.

Thank you!

Comment: Never modify an object that you're iterating over.

Comment: I used python tutor to diagram and saw what you mean it kept rewriting it so it never actually checked that. Thank you! I am getting better at this, but still a rookie and making lots of mistakes.

Comment: You perform `del dict_one[key]` on one line, and the very next line, look up `dict_one[key]`. Unless `dict_one` is some sort of `defaultdict` or other `dict` subclass implementing `__missing__`, that's guaranteed to throw a `KeyError`; you're looking for something you just got rid of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to check to see that every letter in `dict2` has at mapping in `dict1` least as large as that letters mapping in `dict2`?  That's accomplished fairly easily.

```
def can_spell(dict1, dict2):
    try:
        return all(dict1[k] >= v for k, v in dict2.items())
    except KeyError:
        return False
```

This gets every (key, value) pair in `dict2` and then compares `v` with the mapping of that key in `dict1`.  `all` returns `True` iff every expression in that generator comprehension is true.

Comment: It should be `return all(...)`

Comment: @cdonts my only excuse is the hour :p

Comment: That got my there! I was kind of going down that path by using

Comment: if dict_two.items() <= dict_one.items():
           return True
 else: 
        return False

Comment: I upvoted, but my reputation too low still for it to show. I will revote if it doesn't show up when I get high enough. Thank you both so much!

Comment: @answrseeker: Don't use `if dict_two.items() <= dict_one.items(): return True else: return False`. The comparison already returned `True`/`False`. Just do `return dict_two.items() <= dict_one.items()`. That said, not sure where you came up with that, since the answer is rather more complicated.

Comment: Note: If the `dict`s in question were `collections.Counter`s (which combine `dict` behaviors with multi-set like operations), then you could use subset/superset testing, no `items` call required. `return counter1 >= counter2` would be all you needed.

Comment: @ShadowRanger 3.5.3 raises a `TypeError` and claims that `Counter`s are unorderable

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think checking the intersection against `counter2` works `return (counter1 & counter2) == counter2`

Comment: @ShadowRanger I was just trying that method out before I saw Patrick Hough's post.  I am still in the dig the hole further then learn a lot on what to do and what not to do while digging yourself out phase. A few things I can do quite well now, but dictionaries I still learn good and bad by messing up more than I get right currently.

Comment: Huh. Misremembered completely. Yeah, you could use the intersection method (or `subtract` and check for min value below 0), but yeah, not fun.